# Cocapods could not find compatible version for pod Firebase

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I just switched to Mac from Windows 10. I have released my Android version of my Flutter app. Now I am working on the IOS version of my Flutter app. When I am trying to run my app on Mac, I am getting below error.

> ```
> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
>   In Podfile:
>   cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
>   Firebase/Core
> ```

```
  mlkit (from `.symlinks/plugins/mlkit/ios`) was resolved to 0.8.3, which depends on
  Firebase/Core (~> 5.11.0)

  CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
  firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
  Firebase/Auth (~> 5.19) was resolved to 5.19.0, which depends on
  Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.19.0)

  mlkit (from `.symlinks/plugins/mlkit/ios`) was resolved to 0.8.3, which depends on
  Firebase/Core (~> 5.11.0) was resolved to 5.11.0, which depends on
  Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.11.0)

  CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
  In Podfile:
  mlkit (from `.symlinks/plugins/mlkit/ios`) was resolved to 0.8.3, which depends on
  Firebase/Core (~> 5.11.0) was resolved to 5.11.0, which depends on
  Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.11.0) was resolved to 5.11.0, which depends on
  FirebaseCore (= 5.1.6)

  mlkit (from `.symlinks/plugins/mlkit/ios`) was resolved to 0.8.3, which depends on
  Firebase/Core (~> 5.11.0) was resolved to 5.11.0, which depends on
  FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.3.0) was resolved to 5.3.0, which depends on
  FirebaseCore (~> 5.1)
```

Answer (score 23):

**I fixed this by running manual 'pod update' & Flutter 'Packages get'...**

In terminal change directory to:

```
cd FLUTTER_PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH/ios
```

Run pod update:

```
pod update
```

Run Flutter Packages get

```
flutter pub get
```

- Then you should be able to build to iOS
- The first build did take about 3 min longer then normal but returned to normal on following builds.

Comment: I tried to run the pod update from inside the ios folder but it shows the same error.... [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
  cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
  Firebase/Core

Comment: @Sam - Have you updated to the latest versions in your pubspec.yaml file - latest version numbers found at: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/FlutterFire.md / Also have you included Firebase/Core in there too?

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed this by cleaning and reinstalling my pods.**

First, save and quit Xcode.

In terminal:

1. cd to directory
2. > pod deintegrate
3. > pod clean
4. > pod install

(this will take a few minutes)

Reopen the xcworkspace.

Then it should work. (the first build will take a few minutes.)

Comment: There is no `pod clean`.

Comment: use this place of `pod clean`  ==> `pod cache clean --all`